# Filter entries by other entry

Tags: entries, relations, filter, relatedto

There's a section called `locations` and another called `vacancies`. In `vacancies` the admin can assign a `location` entry to a `vacancy`.

On the careers overview page we want to display selected vacancies `block.vacancySelected`.

In the template we loop through all locations and would like to display the number of vacancies per location.

```
{% set lparas = {
    section: 'locations'
    } %}
{% set locations = craft.entries(lparas) %}

{% if locations | length %}
   {% for location in locations %}
      {% set cEntries = block.vacancySelected.relatedTo(location) %}
      {% if cEntries| length %}
         {{ location.locationName }} ({{ cEntries | length }})
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But for some reason it shows all locations and the total number of vacancies per locations. It seems to ignore that we only want to show the locations of the selected vacancies.

Comment: Where does the `block` variable come from?

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to show each location with at least one vacancy, and the number of vacancies for that location? I don't really get what `block.vacancySelected` is?

The way I would do this:

```
{# get all locations #}
{% set allLocations = craft.entries.section('locations').all() %}

{% for location in location %}
    {# get a vacancy count for this location #}
    {% set vacancyCountForLocation = craft.entries.section('vacancies').relatedTo({
        field: 'locationFieldHandle',
        targetElement: location,
    }).count() %}

    {% if vacancyCountForLocation %}
        {{ location.locationName }} ({{ vacancyCountForLocation }})
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To prevent loading all locations, even if they have no vacancies, you could also try (untested):

```
{# get all locations, but only if they have related vacancies #}
{% set allVacancies = craft.entries.section('vacancies').ids() %}
{% set allLocations = craft.entries.section('locations').relatedTo({
    field: 'locationFieldHandle',
    sourceElement: allVacancies,
}).all() %}

{% for location in location %}
    {# get a vacancy count for this location #}
    {% set vacancyCountForLocation = craft.entries.section('vacancies').relatedTo({
        field: 'locationFieldHandle',
        targetElement: location,
    }).count() %}

    {{ location.locationName }} ({{ vacancyCountForLocation }})
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes you understood it correctly. `block.vacancySelected` is a set of vacancies – we only want to show selected vacancies. We want to display each location with at least one of the selected vacancies.